# Implementing \Psr\Cache\CacheItemPoolInterface results in fatal error

Tags: php, namespaces

I'm working an implementation of PHP-FIG's PSR-6 caching recommendation but I'm getting a fatal error that I'm not sure how to resolve.

> Declaration of Whatever\CacheItemPoolInterface::save() must be compatible with Psr\Cache\CacheItemPoolInterface::save(Psr\Cache\CacheItemInterface $item)

I'm accepting the same parameters and returning the same values as the interface class.

Here's a stripped-down version of the code I'm working on.

My implementation class:

```
namespace Whatever;

class CacheItemPoolInterface implements \Psr\Cache\CacheItemPoolInterface {
  ... More methods and such up here...

  public function save(CacheItemInterface $item) {
    $key = $item->getKey();
    $value = $item->get();
    $expiration = $item->getExpiration();
    if (cache_set($key, $value, $this->bin, $expiration)) {
      return TRUE;
    }
    else {
      return FALSE;
    }
  }
  ... Some more stuff down here too...
}
```

Here's the class I'm implementing:

```
<?php

namespace Psr\Cache;

interface CacheItemPoolInterface
{

   /**
    * Persists a cache item immediately.
    *
    * @param CacheItemInterface $item
    *   The cache item to save.
    *
    * @return bool
    *   True if the item was successfully persisted. False if there was an error.
    */
   public function save(CacheItemInterface $item);
}
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You need to add `use` statement to alias the `CacheItemInterface`, because in your current code it is relative you your `Whatever` namespace.

Comment: @tereško I'm not sure if that's it. If I add a use \Whatever\CacheItemInterface, which is my implementation of of \Psr\Cache\CacheItemInterface, I still have the error. 

    `namespace Whatever;
    use CacheItemInterface;
    class CacheItemPoolInterface implements 
   \Psr\Cache\CacheItemPoolInterface { ...etc`

The error seems to be with the declaration of the class/method, not that it can't find the CacheItemInterface class upon execution.

Comment: Please look up what `use` does, regarding class/namespace aliasing.